# Using nunjucks with htmlWebpackPlugin using dynamic vars in the template

Tags: javascript, webpack, nunjucks, html-webpack-plugin

I'm searching a way of using Nunjucks with the htmlWebpackPlugin to generate some html files on webpack compiling.

**What I achieved so far**

I managed to actually generate HTML from nunjucks template files through the [nunjucks-html-loader](https://github.com/ryanhornberger/nunjucks-html-loader/) but looking a bit closer to the code of said loader, the render method is called without sending vars to the templates.

So, for now with the following plugin config, I generate HTML without dynamically inserted vars

```
new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
  filename: path.join(__dirname, '/' + page.filename),
  template: 'nunjucks-html-loader!assets/templates/' + page.name + '.njk'
})
```

**What I tried**

For a testing purpose, I tried some changes on the node_module itself (I know, I know...) and changed

`html = template.render(nunjucksContext);`

into

`html = template.render(nunjucksContext, { globals: global.globals });`

Trying to define `global.globals` in my `webpack.config.js` file but this crashes with the following error

`ERROR in   Error: Child compilation failed:
  Module build failed: TypeError: parentFrame.push is not a function`

which is beyond my comprehension.

**What I want**

Is to use an extendable template engine like nunjucks which allows me to structure my templates like the following

```
<html>
<!-- layout structure inherited from every template -->
</html>
```

Every page I make extends the layout and only overrides some blocks

**What I try to avoid**

Partials like for exemple

header file :

```
<html>
<!-- header layout -->
```

footer file

```
<!-- footer layout -->
</html>
```

Every page I make includes partials

---

So my question is : Is it even possible tu use a template engine supporting inheritance like nunjucks with the htmlWebpackPlugin or is it mandatory to use another one like ejs for exemple and chunking the layout into partials which I do not like?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Alright, so I found a workaround here with the [`nunjucks-isomorphic-loader`](https://github.com/SudoCat/Nunjucks-Isomorphic-Loader/) which seems not super supported but still. It works for now !

Here's my webPack config

```
const path = require('path')
const webpack = require('webpack')
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin')

const DEV_ENV = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'dev'

const wpConfig = {
  entry: './assets/js/app.js',

  output: {
    path: path.resolve('./dist/js'),
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },

  module: {
    rules: [
      // Javascript
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules)/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader'
        }
      },

      // Nunjucks - HTML
      {
        test: /\.njk$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'nunjucks-isomorphic-loader',
            query: {
              root: [path.resolve(__dirname, 'assets/templates')]
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },

  plugins: [
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      DEV_ENV: DEV_ENV
    }),

    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      myOptions: { foo: 'bar' },
      filename: path.join(__dirname, '/' + page.filename),
      template: 'assets/templates/index.njk'
    })
  ]
}

module.exports = wpConfig
```

having the following templates

`_layout.njk`

```
{% set vars = htmlWebpackPlugin.options.myOptions %}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>{{ vars.foo }}</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <header>
    {% block header %}
      <h1 class="header-logo">
        <a href="#">{{ vars.foo }}</a><!-- Outputs bar -->
      </h1>
    {% endblock %}
    </header>

    {% block content %}

    {% endblock %}
  </body>
</html>
```

`index.njk`

```
{% extends "_layout.njk" %}

{% block content %}
here's the content of my `foo` var: {{ vars.foo }}
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: In your example - what is "page" defined as in "page.filepath"? Also, how do you still feel about this approach a year later?

Comment: @StuFurlong I must admit I can't figure out where `page` is defined now but looks like a path. I stripped down unnecessary details in this conf file for more clarity but I seem to have forgotten this one. I don't use template systems anymore (as I fully threw myself into React and Elm) so I cannot really tell you my feelings about this. I think the package I used is not maintained anymore (but still exists). All I can remember is that this was a bit of a hack and nunjucks is not really adapted to this use case.

Comment: thanks for the response, yeah its a shame as I'm looking for just some basic pre-production template creation and nothing quite fits the bill like nunjucks. Looks like people are moving on and webpack doesn't have any real solid integration with it - your approach here is the only thing I could get truly working. Doesn't seem the juice is worth the squeeze (or risk) though. I might check out ejs, thanks!

Comment: This is exactly how I felt at the time! Good luck with you template creation.

Answer (score 2):

I have write [simple-nunjucks-loader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/simple-nunjucks-loader), that have some advantages to other solutions, like tracking down only required dependencies and `html-webpack-plugin` support out of the box.